# WebView2 - intercept and prevent/cancel anchor navigation

Tags: c#, winforms, webview2

In my WinForms app I used WebView2 to show thrird-party content.
When user clicks the link (or other navigation element) inside the webView, the target link should be opened in the default browser (not in the webView).
For most cases I was able to implement desired behaviour with `NewWindowRequested` and `NavigationStarting` events.
But for anchor navigation inside the current page (`<a href="#my_anchor">`) these events are not firing.

There is a `SourceChanged` event, which is fired in case on anchor navigation, and it even allows to determine that this is `in-page` navigation by checking `IsNewDocument`, but it does not allow to cancel the navigation.

I was thinking about js-based solution, something like subscribing to `click` events for all `a` tags or even for whole `document` with further filtering. But I realized that such a solution will not work in many non-trivial cases, including

- dynamically created `a` elements
- keyboard navigation (TAB to select link, Enter to initiate action, so no `click` event)
- the cases when there are a lot of elements (`img`, etc) inside `a` element and user clicked on such an internal element
- when navigation is initiated with js

So, is the way exists to handle and **cancel** *any* navigation, including anchors in the current page?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same request.  I'm using Win32 C++, and for me the NewWindowRequested event does fire on anchor navigation, and I added this implementation to cancel the default behaviour and open the Uri in the default browser instead...

```
// Register a handler for the NewWindowRequested event.
CHECK_FAILURE(m_webView->add_NewWindowRequested(
    Callback<ICoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventHandler>(
        [this](ICoreWebView2* sender, ICoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs* args) {

            // get the target Uri
            LPWSTR sUri;
            CHECK_FAILURE(args->get_Uri(&sUri));

            // and if it was user initiated (e.g. click on an anchor tag)
            BOOL bUserInit;
            CHECK_FAILURE(args->get_IsUserInitiated(&bUserInit));

            if (bUserInit) {
                // cancel default behaviour
                args->put_Handled(TRUE);

                // and open Uri in default browser
                ShellExecute(0, 0, sUri, 0, 0, SW_SHOW);
            }

            return S_OK;
        })
    .Get(), nullptr));
```

Comment: `m_webView` is of type `ICoreWebView2`, am I correct? Could you please also confirm, that your `a` tag does not have `target="_blank"` or something similar? I got `NewWindowRequested` event for links with `target`, but for simple links `<a href="#my_anchor">link</a>` without additional attributes I got nothing.

Comment: I am trying to use this event handler and for some reason it never seems to be fired?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, in my experience, the `NewWindowRequested ` event only fires when you try to navigate to the another page. If you navigate within the current page (by the anchors), the event does not fire.

Comment: Hi @Serg I have it working now. But ... I only want it to work if the URL begins https. If it is file:  then let webview2 handle it.

Comment: @Serg I tried `if (bUserInit && wcsncmp(sUri, L"file:", 5) == 0) {` but it still processes urls prefixed with file.

Comment: @Serg Sorted, :) Needed `!=`.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue, as a workaround I've made this:

```
//MainWindow.xaml
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wv2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        x:Name="MainWindow" 
        x:Class="WebBrowser.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        FontSize="14" Title="WebView2 Test" Width="400" Height="400" WindowStartupLocation="Manual"
        SizeToContent="Manual" Cursor="Wait"
        WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" PreviewKeyDown="AdvertisementWindow_PreviewKeyDown">
    <DockPanel>
        <wv2:WebView2 Name="myWebBrowser"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs Source code

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;

namespace WebBrowser
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private string url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink";

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeAsync();

            myWebBrowser.NavigationStarting += MyWebBrowser_NavigationStarting;
            myWebBrowser.SourceChanged += MyWebBrowser_SourceChanged;
        }

        private void MyWebBrowser_SourceChanged(object sender, CoreWebView2SourceChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string uri = myWebBrowser.Source.ToString();

            if (e.IsNewDocument == false && uri.EndsWith("#Further_reading"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You clicked #Further_reading", "Further Reading");
            }
        }

        async void InitializeAsync()
        {
            await myWebBrowser.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
            myWebBrowser.CoreWebView2.Navigate(url);
        }
   
        private void AdvertisementWindow_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Key == Key.Escape)
            {
                Close();
            }
        }

        private void MyWebBrowser_NavigationStarting(object sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2NavigationStartingEventArgs e)
        {
            //cancel the current event
            if (!e.Uri.ToString().StartsWith(url))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.Uri.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code should open each link in an external browser (the default system browser) and anchors to external pages will be opened in the external browser too. So it means that we cancel navigating in the WebView (e.Cancel = True). Regarding anchors to the same site, we can handle them in the SourceChanged event, and we don't need to stop navigating as it will stay on the same page.

Comment: just for clarification: myWebBrowser is of Type WebView2

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It definitely will be helpful for other users. But unfortunately it does not answer the initial question as your approach just closes the whole browser, but don't gives a way to cancel navigation and stay browser in a state as it was before navigation.

Comment: Like it is anchor navigation we don't need to stop navigation as the browser will stay on the same page, but as you can have a URL to an external site with an anchor I'll change the code the handle this.